# Replacing MongoDB with MySQL in a Node.js app

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I wanted to host my website on A2Hosting which supports Node.js but they only allow connection to the MySQL database. Unfortunately, I am a beginner web developer who has only studied MongoDB so far and my app is also connected to that database, which I am using with the help of Mongoose. My question is, can I easily replace my code so I could use MySQL? Or does it have an entirely different structure, so I should rather forget about hosting my app ever?

I utilize MongoDB at 3 "places" in my app:

1. app.js file - connection setup
2. models/product.js, models/user.js
3. controllers/adminController.js, controllers/realityController.js

Thank you very much for your reply in advance!

Comment: MondoDB and MySQL are two very different technologies. They respond to different requirements. One is NoSQL, the other one is SQL. Don't choose because that's what they offer. Choose what you need. If they don't have it, pick a different provider. Tons of hosting providers out there, for free (gratis) and paid.

Comment: @TheImpaler thank you very much for your response! The thing is, I couldn't find any providers who would offer shared hosting for Node.js alongside MongoDB and I have neither the knowledge, nor the finances for VPS. If such hosting provider existed who would support what I need, please, let me know!